# Wordpress static homepage and sticky posts excerpt

Tags: wordpress, static, sticky

I tried several things but for some reason i'm not able to show sticky excerpts when i choose a static homepage.

The excerpt that is shown  is the excerpt of the static homepage.

Does any body know how to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Comment: I have this same problem and have tried all these solutions. My page, using the showcase.php template from TwentyTwelve, is set as the static front page, which works fine. It just won't get my sticky posts no matter what I put in.

Comment: Whatever the solution is, I think it requires more code than the codex would have you think. I ended up just copying from the standard showcase.php file in 2012 and ended up having to use more html and php to display the sticky posts.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually hard to tell out of nothing.

I would look into this:

In the reading option panel, did you assign the static page in the posts dropdown, if not do so and it should fix your issue !

If you are using a custom template file, are you using a custom wp query ? If you are starting a loop without using a custom query, the default behavior is to return content from the page whose the template is assigned to.

Please add more details if you can't find a solution.

edit: this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen) explains it nicely

Comment: The stickies work prefect as long as i don't set a static page. When i do, the loop will be used for the static page instead of the stickies and i can't start a second loop.

Comment: [wp_reset_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) will let you start a second loop and [wp_reset_postdata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) will let you get the original post data after a custom query.
As explained in the link i provided above the static page in posts mode will default to index.php or home.php. It depends mainly on that 2 files. Can you be more specific about your setup and provide a bit more informations ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution I came up with - makes stickies sticky literally *everywhere* in WP, even admin.

http://interconnectit.com/2146/how-to-make-sticky-posts-even-stickier-in-wordpress/

Comment: FYI you'll need to paste the code from that blog post into your theme's functions.php